# Recursive json to csv with python

Tags: python, json, csv, recursion

I have a json file to convert it in json but the case here is the nested json structure:

> [    {
> "node":[
> {
> "node":[
> {
> "node":[
> {
> "node":[
> {
> "valBool":false,
> "valStr1":[
> "true"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Industry is in bank exclusion list"
> ]
> },
> {
> "valBool":false,
> "valStr1":[
> "true"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Borrower is currently under bankruptcy law"
> ]
> },
> {
> "valBool":false,
> "valStr1":[
> "true"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Borrower is flagged as Unwilling"
> ]
> },
> {
> "valBool":false,
> "valStr1":[
> "true"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Borrower is flagged as non-viable"
> ]
> },
> {
> "valBool":false,
> "valStr1":[
> "true"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Borrower has blocked access of bank to Tiresias"
> ]
> },
> {
> "valBool":false,
> "valStr1":[
> "true"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Borrower is default (NPE/NPF eba status) "
> ]
> },
> {
> "valBool":true,
> "valStr1":[
> "false"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Default value"
> ]
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> },
> {
> "node":[
> {
> "node":[
> {
> "node":[
> {
> "node":[
> {
> "node":[
> {
> "valBool":false,
> "valStr1":[
> "1"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "There are less \nthan 10 employees"
> ]
> },
> {
> "valBool":false,
> "valStr1":[
> "1"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Annual turnover is \nlower than annual \nturnover threshold"
> ]
> },
> {
> "valBool":false,
> "valStr1":[
> "1"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Total assets are \nlower than total \nassets threshold"
> ]
> },
> {
> "valBool":true,
> "valStr1":[
> "0"
> ],
> "valStr2":[
> "Default"
> ]
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> }
> ]    } ]

As you can see 'node' can be find at any level. I tried some recursive aproaches but the output is not what we want.
We need to take every node that has the three values inside and write them to one line on csv.

The expected output should be:

```
valBool,valStr1,valStr2
false,"true","Industry is in bank exclusion list"
false,"true","Borrower is currently under bankruptcy law"
```

I have tried [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10) but the output justs appends each value in new line writing the whole path on key.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the exact expected output for this input? Also please post what you've tried so far so that we can try to see what went wrong.

Comment: OK, next time please post what you have actually done and not a link to a page containing code snippets.  I should not have to navigate through a blog page to find the code you're talking about.  People on SO are willing to help but it's your job to help us as much as possible to help you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider in your recursive function if the data you're
processing is a list or a dictionary.  If it's a list you simply recusively call your function on its items.  If it's a dictionary you try to
print values associated to `'valBool'`, `'valStr1'` and `'valStr2'` if
they are present and recursively call on the value associated to
`'node'` if any.

```py
data = [ { "node":[ { "node":[ { "node":[ { "node":[ { "valBool":False, "valStr1":[ "true" ], "valStr2":[ "Industry is in bank exclusion list" ] }, { "valBool":False, "valStr1":[ "true" ], "valStr2":[ "Borrower is currently under bankruptcy law" ] }, { "valBool": False, "valStr1":[ "true" ], "valStr2":[ "Borrower is flagged as Unwilling" ] }, { "valBool": False, "valStr1":[ "true" ], "valStr2":[ "Borrower is flagged as non-viable" ] }, { "valBool": False, "valStr1":[ "true" ], "valStr2":[ "Borrower has blocked access of bank to Tiresias" ] }, { "valBool":False, "valStr1":[ "true" ], "valStr2":[ "Borrower is default (NPE/NPF eba status) " ] }, { "valBool":True, "valStr1":[ "false" ], "valStr2":[ "Default value" ] } ] } ] }, { "node":[ { "node":[ { "node":[ { "node":[ { "node":[ { "valBool":False, "valStr1":[ "1" ], "valStr2":[ "There are less \nthan 10 employees" ] }, { "valBool":False, "valStr1":[ "1" ], "valStr2":[ "Annual turnover is \nlower than annual \nturnover threshold" ] }, { "valBool":False, "valStr1":[ "1" ], "valStr2":[ "Total assets are \nlower than total \nassets threshold" ] }, { "valBool":True, "valStr1":[ "0" ], "valStr2":[ "Default" ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ]

result = list()
def loop(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:  # data is a list => recursive call on all its items
            loop(item)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):  # data is a dictionary
        try:
            row = f"{data['valBool']};{data['valStr1'][0]};{data['valStr2'][0]}"
            print(row)
            result.append(row)
        except KeyError: # dictionary does not have all valXXX keys
            pass
        if 'node' in data:  # recursive call if the dictionary has a "node" key
            loop(data['node'])

print('valBool;valStr1;valStr2')
loop(data)
```

It's not exactly the output you're expecting, but you'll figure out
how to modify it.

[EDIT] modified the code to put lines in list `result`

Comment: @qoufy thanks a lot. Your reply is the solution. I have nothing to modify.

Comment: Just a quick question on this. How can we store the print messages? Writing to file or appending to string/list? The second unfotunatelly doesn't work.

Comment: @dside I updated the code to put lines in a list.